Compute hessian for a quadratic cost after nullspace projection
I have a set of quadratic costs, where cost $i$ is of the form $$ f_i(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^T Q_i x + b_ix$$ which means the gradient is $$ \frac{df}{dx}(x) = \sum_i Q_ix + b_i$$.
When optimizing these costs I want to treat some as lower priority than others; a lower priority objective shouldn't interfere with satisfying a high priority objective. In gradient descent I can do this by projecting the lower priority gradients into the nullspace of the higher priority gradients. For example, given a high and low priority gradient, $v_h = Q_hx + b_h$ and $v_l = Q_lx + b_l$, the nullspace-projected low priority gradient becomes $$v_l - v_h \frac{v_l \cdot v_h}{v_h \cdot v_h}$$
However, in order to use this priority trick in a quadratic program, I need to compute the hessian for this projected cost. I tried simply projecting $Q_l$ but that did not match my autodiff tests. Is there a relatively simple expression for this projected hessian? Maybe there's a different way to implement this priority idea in QPs?

Can you define a 'projected Hessian'?
